# Why does MongoDB count so long?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, count

I have collection ~2 000 000 documents.
A field `unit` has index : `{"unit" : 1.0}`

Query:

```
db.getCollection('CollectionName').find({"unit":"value"}).count()
```

performs 5 sec (result 200 000 docs)

Query:

```
db.getCollection('CollectionName').find({"unit":"value"})
```

performs 0.005 sec

Why?

Answer (score 3):

`find()` returns a cursor, `find().count()` exhausts that cursor in order to count the number of documents in it.

You might prefer to use [db.collection.count](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/) ,for example:

```
db.getCollection('CollectionName').count({"unit":"value"})
```

Comment: db.collection.count is equivalent db.collection.find

Comment: It is *functionally* equivalent but the *non functionals* are different. `find(...).count()` will read all 200,000 docs and then count them whereas `count(...)` will perform the count server side and only return the number of documents which match the given filter.

Comment: db.getCollection('CollectionName').count({"unit":"value"}) dosen't help, query performs 5 sec

Comment: If you are running a version >= 3.0 then you could try [explaining the count](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.explain/#db.collection.explain), for example:   `db.getCollection('CollectionName').explain().count({"unit":"value"})`. But, the underlying point remains that you are perhaps not making a valid comparison when you compare either form of `count` against `find` since `find` is only returning a cursor whereas `count` is actually reading data and computing a response.